# Android ListView not updating with filter

Tags: java, android

I've got a list view that I'm trying to filter depending on which button the user clicks.

The filter is working, I'm getting the results I expect inside the publishResults method but the list is then never updating. I've got notifyDataSetChanged() but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Min SDK level 21 and compiled 26.

```
    mAdapter = new QuakeAdapter(this, new ArrayList<QuakeItem>());
    ListView earthquakeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    earthquakeListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Setting the filter

```
public void filterList(View view){
    mAdapter.resetData();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FILTER Tsunami" + mAdapter.quakeList);
    mAdapter.getFilter().filter("tsunamiOnly");
}

public void filterListEarthquake(View view){
    mAdapter.resetData();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FILTER earthquake" + mAdapter.quakeList);
    mAdapter.getFilter().filter("earthquakeOnly");
}
```

Custom Adapter

```
public class QuakeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<QuakeItem> implements Filterable {
    public ArrayList<QuakeItem> origQuakeList;
    public ArrayList<QuakeItem> quakeList;
    private Filter quakeFilter;
    private Context mContext;

    public static final String LOG_TAG = QuakeAdapter.class.getName();

    public QuakeAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<QuakeItem> quakeItems){
        super(context, 0, quakeItems);
        origQuakeList = quakeItems;
        quakeList = quakeItems;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent){
        View listItemView = convertView;

        if(listItemView == null){
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false
            );
        }

        QuakeItem currentItem = getItem(position);

        double mag = currentItem.getMagnitude();

        TextView magnitudeTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.magnitudeView);
        magnitudeTextView.setText(formatMagnitude(mag));

        GradientDrawable magnitudeCircle = (GradientDrawable) magnitudeTextView.getBackground();
        int magnitudeColour = getMagnitudeColour(mag);
        magnitudeCircle.setColor(magnitudeColour);

        int isTsunami = currentItem.getTsunami();
        int strokeColor = magnitudeColour;
        if (isTsunami==1){
            strokeColor = Color.BLACK;
        }
        magnitudeCircle.setStroke(6, strokeColor);

        String[] formattedString = formatLocation(currentItem.getLocation());

        TextView locationOffsetTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.locationOffsetView);
        locationOffsetTextView.setText(formattedString[0]);

        TextView locationTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.locationView);
        locationTextView.setText(formattedString[1]);

        Long timeInMilliseconds = currentItem.getTime();

        TextView timeTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.timeView);
        timeTextView.setText(formatTime(timeInMilliseconds));

        TextView dateTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.dateView);
        dateTextView.setText(formatDate(timeInMilliseconds));

        return listItemView;
    }

    public void resetData() {
        quakeList = origQuakeList;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (quakeFilter == null)
            quakeFilter = new QuakeFilter();

        return quakeFilter;
    }

    private class QuakeFilter extends Filter{
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                // No filter found, return original list
                results.values = origQuakeList;
                results.count = origQuakeList.size();
            } else {
                // Perform filter
                ArrayList<QuakeItem> nQuakeList = new ArrayList<QuakeItem>();

                switch (constraint.toString()){
                    case "tsunamiOnly":
                        for (QuakeItem q : quakeList){
                            if (q.getTsunami() == 1){
                                nQuakeList.add(q);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "earthquakeOnly":
                        for (QuakeItem q : quakeList){
                            if (q.getTsunami() == 0){
                                nQuakeList.add(q);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }

                results.values = nQuakeList;
                results.count = nQuakeList.size();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults filterResults) {
            if (filterResults.count == 0){
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            } else {
                quakeList = (ArrayList<QuakeItem>) filterResults.values;
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FILTER " + quakeList);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Has `getView()` in ArrayAdapter?

Comment: Yes sorry, I just didn't include it in the code snippet to cut down on the amount of code.

Comment: Are you doing UI updates in an Async thread? If so, that could cause display problems in the main UI.

Comment: I've got an Async Loader that gets the list data from an api and then updates the adapter onLoadFinished(). I then try and filter the list once the Loader has finished populating the list. Will that be causing the problems?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem. As expected it was something stupid.

I was missing getCount, getItem and getItemId in my adapter.

```
public int getCount() {
    return quakeList.size();
}

public QuakeItem getItem(int position) {
    return quakeList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return quakeList.get(position).hashCode();
}
```